# Do windows program IDs change when running python code vs running a pyinstaller exe?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, win32com

I have some python code that is running fine through my IDE (pycharm).

After I use the auto-py-to-exe (a gui for pyinstaller) to create an exe and run that, I get the error that is pasted below.

I created the exe in the same environment, so win32com is installed where I am running pyinstaller. While searching around for the error, it said something this error meaning that the program ID was incorrect, but why would the program ID work in pycharm, but not the exe? Thanks for any help, I really appreciate it!

Line 181:

```
olApp = win32.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
olNS = olApp.GetNameSpace('MAPI')
```

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 86, in _GetGoodDispatch
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221021, 'Operation unavailable', None, None)

 

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pamsplusemail.py", line 181, in <module>
  File "win32com\client\__init__.py", line 117, in Dispatch
  File "win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 106, in _GetGoodDispatchAndUserName
  File "win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 88, in _GetGoodDispatch
pywintypes.com_error: (-2146959355, 'Server execution failed', None, None)
[21972] Failed to execute script 'pamsplusemail' due to unhandled exception!
```